# Problema al rescribir el namespace en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rutas, namespace

soy nuevo en laravel y en este momento me encuentro probando los comandos para poder crear controlladores con el comando:

```
php artisan make:controller /list/listController
```

Lo que quiero es poder crear el controlador dentro de una carpeta especifica y no dentro de Controllers, sin embargo cuando miro las rutas en consola me sale este error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

y me sale un error con el namespace del controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\list;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class listController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
        
    }
}
```

No entiendo porque da error el namespace por eso agradezco a la persona que pueda ayudarme a solucionar esto gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a crear el controlador sin la primera barra

```
php artisan make:controller list/listController
```

Yo siempre los creo así y no tengo problemas,

Comment: Lo hice como me dijiste y funciono como queria, gracias compañero.

Answer (score 3):

artisan espera que le pases el nombre de la clase. Si pones el nombre sin espacio de nombre, e.g.:

```
 php artisan make:controller SomeController
```

por convención creará un archivo

```
 app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php
```

En donde se declara una clase `SomeController` en el espacio de nombres `App\Http\Controllers`, luego su FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name) es `App\Http\Controllers\SomeController`. Cuando quieras instanciar era clase, composer sabrá encontrar el archivo físico, dado que sabe que `app` es el espacio de nombres `App` y de ahí hacia adentro todo sigue el estándar PSR4.

Si tú quieres crear tu controller en otra carpeta tienes que declararlo con su espacio de nombres completo, pero además escapando los backslashes:

```
  php artisan make:controller App\\Http\\Controllers\\List\\ListController
```

Aunque técnicamente puedes poner un namespace en minúsculas, y una clase en camelCase, es sano que sigas la convención [PSR2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) y no tengas que recordar cómo le pusiste a una clase o dónde.